# what does mask_fill in pytorch do here

Tags: pytorch

I have tensor named "k1" which is in shape 3,1,1,9 and also have p1 tensor in shape of 3,7,9,9 and I wanna know what does the line below do?

```
p1 = p1 .masked_fill(k1== 0, float("-1e30"))
```

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation page](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.masked_fill_.html#torch.Tensor.masked_fill_) describes it:

> `Tensor.masked_fill(mask, value)` 
> Fills elements of `self` tensor with value where `mask` is `True`. The shape of `mask` must be broadcastable with the shape of the underlying tensor.

In your case it will place in `p1` the value of `float("-1e30")` at the positions where `k1` is equal to zero. Since `k1` has singleton dimensions its shape will be broadcasted to the shape of `p1`.